Gramjs addEventHandler stops getting new updates after few minutes
I'm having a problem listening for new messages. After a couple of minutes, the addEventHandler method stops working. What could be happening?
this.client = this.client = new TelegramClient(this.stringSession, TELEGRAM_API_ID, TELEGRAM_API_HASH, {
  connectionRetries: 5
})

this.client.addEventHandler(this.eventHandler.bind(this), new NewMessage({ chats: CHANNELS_TO_LISTEN }))

private async eventHandler(event: NewMessageEvent) {
  try {
    if (!event) {
      logger.error(`The msg received is null or undefined`)
    }
    logger.trace(`New msg received: ${event.message.message}`)
    this.emit('call', event.message)
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(`Error handling event: ${error}`)
  }
}

I don't think it's a connection problem since it always stays connected without any problems.
